# The Real Problem of Being

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, being

Suppose you come into existence as a human named Tom.

The Creator tells you the one and only rule of the universe: be who you choose to be.

This is fun. You design yourself, and you choose you hair texture, eye color, skin color. And you live in the perfect society, doing what you think is best for your well-being.

After a while, you get sick of being a man. So you go to the Creator and ask him to make you into a woman. Because it is consistent with the one and only rule, it happens and you're now a young woman. You get married and then you have children and become a mother. The children grow old and goes to war and your husband has an affair with a foreign woman and ditches you.

Then, out of boredom, you get the desire to be an animal. You ask the Creator "I want to be a cow!" And *POOF* you're a four-footed cloven-hooved ungulate. But because cows are not self-aware, this is your final terminal state. You undid your own ability to be who you choose to be.

The Creator realizes that, for being, "be who you choose to be" is not the answer, because it has no safe-guards.

So now we branch into a different parallel universe. You come into existence as a human named John. The Creator tells John the new rule of the universe.

"John, the universe has only one rule: you are who I say you are." The Creator isn't going to divulge the history behind this rule and its case precedence with Operation Tom (all laws come from case precedence after all), so He just says it flat.

John, then, goes and lives his life. He gets married, plants a garden, and has children. John then grows old and full of years and dies. John goes back to the Creator to receive what is his due: exclusion from the World to Come.

John is bemused. "Why?" he asks.

The Creator responds: "...because you're evil!"

"But I don't want to be evil. I want to be a different type of person."

The Creator responds: "...who are you to question Me and My wisdom?!"

And so John goes into the outer darkness, where there is weeping and gnashing of teeth.

---

Obviously both John and Tom's fates are undesirable. Tom loses because "be who you choose to be", while guaranteeing that you'll be happy, has nothing to restrain itself, so there's nothing to prevent you from choosing in a way that will make you lose. It's too chaotic. John loses because Aristotle's law of identity, while it did its intended function in keeping John from losing himself by choosing to be the wrong sort of being, rests on the dubious presumption that the person you're born as is inherently good.

What is the correct solution to the problem of being?

Comment: free will and lack of inherent evil doesn't mean we can be anything we choose. it's a false dichotomy

Comment: If free will doesn't mean being anything we choose, then free will is a choice on whether you choose to actualize your potential or not. In other words, you have free choice in the same way a test taker on a multiple choice test has free choice: he can choose any way he wants, but he has to choose the right way on pain of penalty.

Comment: that's not the same as inherent evil. it just means that we can suffer or choose poorly in some way. this time the false dichotomy is either never suffering or being evil

Comment: OP presented two extreme systems with inherent evil. Yes there is a system without inherent evil. But neither of these two systems are it. You can see the system without inherent evil (which is why you don't understand). But how do you externalize that system on paper?

Comment: neither the evil of chaotic freedom nor the evil of complete unfreedom? it's an artifical scenario. if you want to live free but not arbitarily, then i think the phrase is authentic, idk

Comment: @prof_ghost So what's the right mix?

Comment: i think whether the middle is neither extreme or can include them both is a difficult question, but aside from that it depends on the scenario i guess

Comment: To my understanding you are "touching upon" the concepts of free-will and fate.
I generally agree with @Marco Ocram answer - it's about the choises - and subsequently the "key point" here is what are these "wise choices". The bottom line for me is that choices (free-will) have consequences (fate). It's all about taking responsibility of yourself.

Comment: Didn't some guy say something about "the Middle Way" a long time ago? Hmm...

Answer (score 3):

If your question boils down to this...

1. 'Be who you choose to be' might result in you choosing to be in some wanting state.
2. 'Be who you are' might result in you being and remaining innately in some wanting state.
3. Given 1) and 2) is there an better alternative?

... then the obvious answer is be who you choose to be but make wise choices.

Comment: Wise is a vague word and there's a lot of debate over what is wise and what is not. Traditionalists say that it's never a wise choice to choose your gender, but some pediatricians disagree.

Comment: @HolyKnowing sure I agree with you. Not only is wisdom ill-defined, but so is the idea of a good end-state. The key is to try to be clear about the latter and narrow your definition of wisdom to match it. If a good end state includes, for example, not being obese, then the definition of wise choices would not include those that lead to obesity.

Answer (score 0):

Take the middle way between extremes: neither sensual indulgence (now I'll be a cow) nor ascetic suffering (I am inherently evil). There are other ways of framing the dichotomy.

Comment: What are the other ways?

Comment: self regulation... awareness of freedom... idk @HolyKnowing